# sources about SVD complexity

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

I've heard that the complexity of SVD(singular values decomposition) of a $n \times m$ matrix is $O(mn^2)$ when  $m>n$.(I mean the complexity to find out the singular vectors and the singular values.)

Would you please introduce me some books, papers,... to know about its proof?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Matrix computations" by Golub and Van Loan, and in fact it's O(mn^2) only if you need only singular values, for full SVD (all 3 matrices) it's O(mn^2 + n^3).